# Complex CSS selector

Tags: css, selector

I have a nightmare CMS to work with - it only spits out tables within tables within tables etc al, some nested, some sibling.  There are no `class`es or `id`s, so I am trying to select in the only way left.

When mousing over HTML in Firebug it puts out a display like this (simplified version):

```
html/body/div/div[3]/table[3]
```

I tried this CSS selector to replicate it:

```
html body div div:nth-child[3]
```

But it doesn't work; it breaks down at the :nth-child selector.  How can I write a CSS selector to access the above element?

Comment: As is evident in @ŠimeVidas answer, css selectors use parentheses, not square brackets.  So `:nth-child(3)` is correct but `:nth-child[3]` is not.   Note that Firefox is giving you an XPath(like) expression, so there's some translation to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
body > div > div:nth-child(3) > table:nth-child(3)
```

But this is as inefficient as CSS selectors can get. Are you sure that your CMS doesn't give you any IDs or classes?